# Excel ActiveX Combobox shows previous selection when losing focus

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have this code which fills a combobox on Sheet1 with the Name column of Table1 on Sheet2.

```
Public Sub Worksheet_Activate()
   Me.ComboBox1.List = Worksheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Table1")_
   .ListColumns("Name").DataBodyRange.Value
End Sub
```

Works fine but it has a weird effect when I click off the combobox onto the sheet.  The selected entry in the box quickly flashes to the previous entry.  For example, the currently selected item is "b" and then I select "c".  If I click on the worksheet the entry in the box quickly flashes to "b" before going back to "c".

I've put this code alone in a new file and I still get the same effect.  Has anyone else seen this?

Edit regarding reason for Public Sub:

Forgot to include the `Workbook_Open` code so that Sheet1 is considered Activated when you open the Workbook.  But it doesn't matter if I keep that code or not, I still see the effect.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Call ActiveSheet.Worksheet_Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Happens for me even without VBA code so I guess you're stuck with it

Comment: well that's annoying.  I searched and didn't see anyone else mention it before.  It's the kind of thing that just nags at me.

Comment: Not sure why it is a Public Sub, but I don't get this phenomenon on Excel 2010. Your code is in **Sheet1** object?

Comment: Yes it's in Sheet1.  This is Excel 365.  I forgot to include the Workbook_Open code which calls Worksheet_Activate.  That's why it's Public.  Otherwise when you first open up the Worksheet it's not considered Activated so you won't get the drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `LostFocus` event with code that selects a cell on your worksheet should cause the flicker not to happen when you select a cell after changing the ComboBox's value.

Like the following:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_LostFocus()
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").select
End Sub
```